# Looking up the value associated with the previous date of same ticker

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a reproducible example that only has 4 rows, but I am using this for a 12m row dataset.

Is there an easier way to achieve what the following code does? As you can see there are a lot of steps.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['1/1/2023','ABC',0.01],['1/1/2023','XYZ',0.09],['1/7/2023','ABC',0.0],['1/7/2023','XYZ',0.03]],columns=['date','ticker','price'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
dates = pd.DataFrame(df['date'].unique(),columns=['date'])
dates['lastweek'] = dates['date'].shift(1)
tmp = df[['date','ticker']]
tmp = tmp.merge(dates,on='date',how='left')
tmp = tmp.merge(df[['date','ticker','price']],left_on=['lastweek','ticker'],right_on=['date','ticker'])
tmp['price'] = tmp['price'].fillna(0)
tmp = tmp.drop(columns=['date_y'])
tmp = tmp.rename(columns={'date_x':'date','price':'lastweekprice'})
df = df.merge(tmp[['date','ticker','lastweekprice']],on=['date','ticker'],how='left')
```

Answer (score -1):

**Code**

If your data is by week, as in your example, and you want to get the previous week's data by ticker, you can use `groupby` + `shift`.

```
out = df.assign(lastweekprice=df.groupby('ticker')['price'].shift())
```

out:

```
    date        ticker  price   lastweekprice
0   1/1/2023    ABC     0.01    NaN
1   1/1/2023    XYZ     0.09    NaN
2   1/7/2023    ABC     0.00    0.01
3   1/7/2023    XYZ     0.03    0.09
```

In addition, it will be much easier to get a response by clearly explaining what you want in terms of input and desired output, rather than having to read your unnecessary and lengthy code to clearly understand what you need to do and find ways to improve your code.